# Lexing error while running build ninja command

Tags: ninja

I am using **ninja** to build a program for the first time. I run the command `ninja` from the ***cmd*** but get the error:
 `ninja: error: build.ninja:3: lexing error`

What is the issue?

Here is my `build.ninja` file:

```
rule compile 
  command = gcc -Wall -c $in -o $out 

rule link
  command = gcc $in -o $out 

build hello.o: compile main.c 
build hello: link hello.o `
```

and here is `main.c`:

```
int main() {
    printf("Hello world\n");

    return 0;
}
```